# Javascript toggle not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you  can see here in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjNLM/273/), the toggle for the login and register is working just fine, however when I am testing this on my local machine it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" for bt2.

Here is the code

CSS

```
#login
{

}
#register
{
    display:none;
}
#container{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input, select { 
    padding: 9px; 
    border: solid 1px #E5E5E5; 
    outline: 0; 
    font: normal 13px/100% Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
    width: 200px; 
    background: #FFFFFF url('bg_form.png') left top repeat-x; 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE 1px, #FFFFFF 25px); 
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    } 

select { 
    width: auto; 
       } 

input:hover, select:hover, 
input:focus, select:focus { 
    border-color: #C9C9C9; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 0px 8px; 
    } 


input[type=submit] { 
    width: auto; 
    padding: 9px 15px; 
    background: #617798; 
    border: 0; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<button id="bt1" type="button"> Login
</button>
<button id="bt2" type="button">Register
</button>
<br>
<div id="login">
Login Form
</div>
<div id="register">
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Salutation
</td>
<td>
<select name="Salutation">
<option value="Ms">Ms</option>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Dr">Dr</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
First Name
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="F_Name">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Last Name
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="L_Name">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
E-Mail
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Password(Min 6 characters)
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="pass">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Phone Number(10 digit)
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="P_Number">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input type="Submit" value="Get Started" name="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function swap(login, register) {
    document.getElementById(login).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(register).style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('bt1').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    swap('login','register');
});
document.getElementById('bt2').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    swap('register','login');
});
```

I have tried everything I could to understand the reason behind this issue however it seems that I am unable to do so.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you loading your script?

Comment: @Shomz Within the <script> tag

Comment: Which is in the <head>?

Comment: Thought so, wrote you an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loading your script in the HTML head, and none of the DOM elements exist at that time, causing the addEventListener method to be called on undefined, which throws an error.

Two solutions:

- either wrap the code in the window onload listener
- or simply load the script at the end of the HTML body

Comment: end of the html document right?

Comment: Just before the closing body tag

Comment: OK attempting it now

Comment: Thanks for saving the day @Shomz.

Its the first time I am working under a deadline hence the outcome.

Comment: If you mark an answer as ACCEPTED you get 2 rep points for yourself.

Comment: @CAO -- ahh -- 15 minutes before you can accept...I did not know that.  Thanks.